# Asymptotic analysis of agda functions inside agda

Tags: asymptotic-complexity, agda, theorem-proving

Is it possible to asymptotically analyze agda functions' runtime or memory inside agda itself? I'm trying to come up with something like this. Suppose I have this agda function:

```
data L : Nat → Set where
  [] : L zero
  list : ∀ {n} → Nat → L n → L (suc n)

f : ∀ {n} → L n → Nat
f [] = 0
f (list x xs) = f xs
```

I want to prove a theorem in agda that'd ultimately mean something like `f ∈ O[n]`. However, this is rather hard since I now need to prove something about the implementation of `f` rather than its type. I tried using some reflection and metaprogramming, but without much success. I guess the algorithm I have in my mind is something like getting all terms of `f` one by one like lisp.

The biggest trouble is, obviously, `O[n]` is not well defined, I need to be able to construct this class from `n` of `L n`. Then, I need `f` as `f : L n -> Nat` so that `thm : ∀ {n} -> (f : L n -> Nat) -> f ∈ (O n)`. But then `f` is now not bound to the `f` we're interest in. Instead, it's any function `f` from a list to a natural. Therefore, this is clearly false, so it cannot be proven.

Is there a way to prove something like this?

Comment: See e.g. Danielsson's [Lightweight Semiformal Time Complexity Analysis for Purely Functional Data Structures](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/publications/danielsson-popl2008.html)

Comment: Hey @gallais thank you for the reply but unfortunately that link gives 404 error to me.

Comment: It's this paper: https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1328457